# Shuffled order: A food delivery person is out to delivers 6 dishes to 4 different households

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, permutations

A food delivery person is out to delivers 6 dishes to 4 different households:
household 1 get dish 1
household 2 get dish 2
household 3 get dish 3,4
household 4 get dish 5,6

A computer malfunction randomly reshuffled the order of the dishes a) what is the sample space of the reordered dishes b) what is the probability that household 1,2,3 did not get all their order?

For this problem I assume that the sample space is the possible permutations of the sequence of dishes

as for the second question since we get 6! possible reshuffled sequence, and of these possible outcomes there are 4 outcomes where 1,2,3 still get all their orders $$\{(1,2,3,4,5,6), (1,2,3,4,6,5), (1,2,4,3,5,6), (1,2,4,3,6,5)\},$$ so I reasoned that the probability should be $1-\dfrac 4{6!}$.

However, I am not sure if it is the right result, or I should approach problem differently?

Comment: The sample space doesn't consist of all possible permutations of the six dishes. Such a sample space would distinguish outcomes like $123456$ and $124365$ which shouldn't be regarded as distinct. Have you considered inclusion/exclusion?

Comment: @MatthewH.  I disagree, and regard the OP's (i.e. original poster's) analysis as both accurate and valid.  That is, when you *combinatorically* compute the probability as $$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}},$$ you have the option of deeming order of selection as either relevant or irrelevant, as long as you are consistent between $N$ and $D$.  That is either order is relevant for both, or order is irrelevant for both.  So, I agree with the OP's computation of $$1 - \frac{4}{6!}.$$

Comment: To the OP: +1 for your question for nice work shown, independent of whether your answer is accurate.  However, going forward, please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to display Math at Math SE.

Comment: @MatthewH. Inclusion-Exclusion is unneeded here, because you merely need to compute the complement of the **intersection** of the events of Households 1,2,3 all getting their orders correctly.  Inclusion-Exclusion is appropriate when you need to compute the *union* of events, not their intersection.  So, Inclusion-Exclusion would be needed for the *alternative* question of what is the probability that at least one of households $1,2,$ or $3$ got their orders correctly.

Comment: @MatthewH. It occurs to me that you could construe the original problem as yielding to the computation of the *union* of the complementary events.  That is if $F_1, F_2, F_3$ are the respective events of households $1,2,3$ each getting their order wrong, then you do in fact want to calculate $$p(F_1 \cup F_2 \cup F_3).$$  However, per my previous comments, that is an unnecessary complication.

Comment: @user2661923 I incorrectly thought we were supposed to compute the probability that households 1,2, and 3 all get the wrong order i.e. $$p(F_1 \cap F_2 \cap F_3)$$ Here, $F_j$ is the event the $j^{\text{the}}$ household doesn't get the correct order. When you solve this problem combinatorically you are certainly allowed to consider the plates as ordered or unordered, as long as your consistent with your counting.

Comment: But the sample space is an entirely different story, which is the set $$\Omega=\Big\{(a_1,a_2,\{a_3,a_4\},\{a_5,a_6\}): a_1,...,a_6\in [6]\Big\}$$ Describing the sample space is more rigid in terms how you describe possible outcomes.

Comment: @MatthewH. Arguable.  The definition of the sample space is based on the underlying *atoms* (i.e. pertinent events).  You can validly define the events as having order matter.  The definition of the sample space is not constrained by the question being asked.  Just because the question is focusing on (for example) whether Household-1 got their order correctly does not mean that the sample space atoms need to be the combinations of orders assigned to the households.  Instead, it can be the permutations of orders assigned to the households.

Comment: Unless you introduce more details to the problem to regard permutations of the orders within $H_3$ and $H_4$ as distinguishable I think the sample space I propose is the most natural. But I do agree that one could validly define outcomes so that order matters within $H_3$ and $H_4$ i.e. $(a_3,a_4)=(4,5)$ means Jack gets order $4$ and Jill gets order $5$ whereas $(a_3,a_4)=(5,4)$ means the reverse. Your willingness (and others on this site) to swap interpretations of outcomes being unordered to ordered has helped me with my own countering strategies, so thank you! That's why I joined MSE